# How to make an intro animation dissappear at the end or lead to a homepage with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm struggling a lil with my CSS code when trying to make an intro animation disappear or become transparent once it's finished, so we can see the rest of the HTML (the homepage).

here's what I'm talking about:

```css
    body {
        background: #000;
    }
    
    .container{
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .container span {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .text1 {
        color: white;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background: black;
        position: relative;
        animation: text 4s 1;
    }
    
    .text2{
        font-size: 30px;
        color: coral;
    }
    
    @keyframes text {
        0% {
            color: black;
            margin-bottom: -40px;
        }
        30% {
            letter-spacing: 25px;
            margin-bottom: -40px;
        }
        75% {
            letter-spacing: 8px;
            margin-bottom: -40px;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="animationbkg">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="text1"> Welcome to blablabla</span>
            <span class="text2"> Your journey to blablabla</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <main>
            <div class="box1">
                <h1>SEEK, STRIVE, SUCCEED</h1>
            </div>
        </main>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

***NOW, what I want to do is that on my keyframe, the black background and the text become transparent or simply disappear once it reaches 100%; so we can see the homepage (main of the HTML)
Regards!***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is the CSS that actually uses an animation? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor its in the post and you can run code snippet to see it in action.

Comment: @imvain2 sure that affects the text, I was more looking for the code of making it disappear. I was curious what OP tried to do this - since there is no animation attached to the `animationbkg` element.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to animate your loading container to fade out somehow so that that the underlying content can appear. Something like this :-

```
.animationbkg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: black;
    animation: fadeOut 1s forwards 4s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Notice that we've set a delay of 4s to the fadeOut animation, this ensures that the .animationbkg container fades out only after your initial text animation has finished.

The position : fixed, and z-index: 1 just make sure that your animation container is stacked on the top and occupies the entire screen.

Also make sure that you use a `forwards` animation fill mode so that the elements retain the property that they acquired in the last keyframe of the animation.

Comment: @JorgeBernardoMartnezDeLos glad to help!